# changing the database before every test

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, sql-server-ce, datacontext

I am writing some profiling tests for certain methods like adding customers (different batch sizes 100, 1000, 10000) to customers table in the database. I am using SqlCE database because of its support from LINQ.

Now to reach the ideal case, i am changing the database before every test so that every test will have same database. for that i am using File.Copy() but while using db.customers.FirstOrDefault() in the second test, i am getting the error "The database file may be corrupted. Run the repair utility to check the database file."

I am clearing the data context after the test. The problem also may be with linq. I am not sure.Any idea of solving this. or any alternative to this approach. Any suggestions are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do unit testing like that, it is error-prone and slow.

Instead, use database transactions, and rollback the data at the end of the tests, or when required (say per test).

Comment: This is how we roll on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Internally SqlCE is doing a lot of re-structuring so wanted to provide a new copy itself. Why is it that, this approach is error-prone. and how can i use transactions with `LINQ`

Comment: @Prakash: Error prone due to what you mentioned before, also 'forgetting' to clean up correctly. I dont understand what you mean by restructuring. A transaction will capture everything you do, including schema changes AFAIK. As for using transactions, that is another question that has probably been asked before. Tip: Use search.

Comment: @Jarrod Dixon: That can mean sooo many things :) Hint please. (nice poetry btw)

Comment: @Leppie: Probably a different word suits there, optimization. that is, there is a timing difference between inserting the content first time, second and third times. First time is very slow. and the change is exponentially decreasing.

Comment: @Leppie: I just read that, transaction rollback will be done in a different thread. If it is so then i will need to wait till that thread finishes it's work.

Comment: @Prakash: You should not have to worry about the internals. I for one dont. Just do `transaction.Rollback()` in a `finally` clause.

Comment: @Leppie: I forgot one thing. If I use transactions, profiling tests can't provide exact timings. Since the data is not really being inserted into the database. Am i right..?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative might be to have a function that clears the data in the db (or in specific tables) and populates it to your desired start-state. This would then be run before you begin your tests (or before individual tests, depending on the requirements). Using this method would make `File.Copy()` unnecessary.

Comment: I felt that, this approach would be a headache so tried to copy the db itself. But thanks , yaar. it will be a backup reminder for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite with a in-memory database.

SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = :memory:");

ps: keep leppie answer in mind

Comment: But I am using SQL CE database. The whole project is using Compact edition.

Comment: @Prakash in production, but can't you inject sqlite in the unit tests? Or do you specific SQL CE features? For SQLite linq support: http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/

Comment: But all my tests are profiling db operations. so i can't use some other database. In fact, we recently had a discussion on moving to sql lite because of speed.